# Use internet connection of server, on a client, using proxy or something

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssh, vpn, proxy, socks

I am working around to find the best and simplest solution to this:

Assume we have a windows server 2008 R2 (name this A) with 2 network card configured, one is connected to Internet and another is connected to company LAN. so I am able to see both internet and LAN from this server A.

My PC (name it B) just connected to LAN and there is no internet connection on B.

The goal is to use the Internet of A on B.

I want to be able to input the IP address  and port of A into B's browser e.g. Firefox (like a proxy server) and use the internet of A.

How can this possible using SSH, Socks Proxy, VPN or etc.

thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

This LAN is our organization LAN that is governmental and I am not allowed to put a router or change the network setup. I have access to A remotely and my role is administrator on A. I can browse 
Internet on A, but it is a company businesses server! I don't want to open my email on that. I don't have Internet access on my desktop PC , B. hope I was clear guys!

Comment: instead of downvoting this quastion, please give me the answer.

Comment: Its being downvoted because its a junk question. Why not buy a cheap $50 Linksys router, and actually put the server and workstations behind it? What goal (besides internet access) are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Bah, the reason for the downvote you give I believe is appaling. Not everybody sees spending money as the solution. Instead this person is trying to think outside the square which should be appreciated. True, he may not have developed this site's skills of asking a question in a format its members are comfortable with but that is the course many of us take when starting somehwere new. Welcome to Serverfault vaheeds, I hope you've got a thick skin.

Comment: `"Try **including attempted solutions**, why they didn't work, and the expected results"` - those are the big reasons the question was closed in my opinion.

Comment: thanks @captcha! I think I was not clear on my quastion. this LAN is our organization LAN that is governmental. I am not allowed to put a router or change the network setup. please read EDIT. by the way @DanBig! your very easy thinking!

Comment: @vaheeds You could install OpenVPN on the machine A. You can then open a single port that you can connect to from machine B. Once connected you can then use machine A as the default gateway for machine B, hence enable internet access on machine B through machine A. I have set up a similar setup on Linux and it works very well. You can find documentation for OpenVPN here: https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html

Comment: you'r totally right @captcha. finally someone solve this! thank you very much . this is the right answer. why don't you post this as an answer!?

Comment: @vaheeds Thanks for the feedback. OpenVPN has many features, so I would really take it step by step. Just a simple static point to point vpn and then add options. The two options in your client file to make use of the remote internet connection as your gatway are: 'redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp' and 'dhcp-option DNS 10.8.9.1'. The ip address is machine A's vpn address when connected. Unfortunately, people much smarter than us found your question off-topic. In their infinite wisdom they have put it on hold and I can therfore not provide an Answer that you can vote on...

Answer (score 2):

A quick search would yield you a result for Internet Connection Sharing.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770507(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: this LAN is not a small office network. we have a separate DHCP server, DNS server, Gateway,Active Directory server , etc. Also I don't want to share the Internet all over the LAN, just in my PC.

Comment: ICS doesn't help me on this at all.